# Проблема с отображением результата в textbox

Tags: php

```
Enter string: <input type="text" name="textbox1" size="150" value="1+2"><br/><br/>             
First part:  <input type="text" name="textbox2" size="150" value=""><br/><br/> 
Second part:  <input type="text" name="textbox3" size="150" value=<?php echo $c; ?>><br/><br/>      
 <button><input name="Result" type="submit"></button>
```

Почему в textbox3 не отображается результат 1го и 2го textbox'a ?

Comment: Но там даже нет атрибута `value`. `1+2` нужно вынести в переменную, например `$c = 1+2;`. Тогда можно будет и в третье поле вывести значение в атрибут `value`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов поправил..

Comment: А, `$c`, как вычисляется?

Comment: $c=$a+$b , только этот результат надо в textbox записать , а не просто, без textbox'a

Comment: Сначала нужно объявить переменные, подсчитать, а уже после записывать результаты в каждый `input`. PHP не будет динамически это делать, при изменении пользователем значений в полях `input`, а только единожды при отрисовки страницы.